# ImageLoader = ImageLoaderFactory.create( context );

Tags: java, android-studio, universal-image-loader

I searched what `ImageLoaderFactory.create( context )` does but I don't understand.

ImageLoader = ImageLoaderFactory.create( context );

I know that `ImageLoader` is for Image downloaded on the web.

Comment: What is your question? Please explain what you have understood so far and what is unclear to you.

Comment: i don't understand why we use, ImageLoaderFactory.create( context ) what is this purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

The following snipet is for ImageLoader to load images from any url inside your project folder:

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path;
import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil;

public class ImageLoaderImpl implements IImageLoader {

@Override
public Image loadImage(Class<?> clazz, String path) {
    Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(clazz);
    URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path(path), null);
    ImageDescriptor imageDescr = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
    return imageDescr.createImage();
}

}
```

You can implement an ImageLoaderFactory to retrieve IImageLoader objects.
Then, for example, at your code you can load images from your project folder (you have created a 'icon' folder inside your project:

```
imageLoader.loadImage(this.getClass(), "icons/myicon.png");
```